# SASS/SCSS - Color switch on body doesn't work

Tags: css, sass

I want to build a simple theme color switcher in CSS with SASS pre-processor. When I click a button, background color, for example, switches from white to black / black to white. The functionality is working on my div, on my button, but not on my body (on which the background color is set). Do you know why ?

Thanks

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="toggle-btn">Toggle theme</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS/SCSS

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

:root {
    font-size: 14px;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .dark-theme & {
        background-color: black;
    }
}

.container {
    border: 2px solid red;

    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    transition: all .3s;

    .dark-theme & {
        background-color: black;
    }
}

.toggle-btn {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;

    .dark-theme & {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

JS

```
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme'));
```

[code](https://codepen.io/coursudemy/pen/eYzZjXP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing as

```
body {
    .dark-theme & {
        background-color: black;
       }
    }
```

which means dark-theme classname `inside` of body element. Change to `&.dark-theme` which `&` means `within` body element.

```
body {
 &.dark-theme {
        background-color: black;
    }
  }
```